# Stack Implementations in C

Tags: c

I’m stuck trying to figure out what, exactly, are the definitions of the following stack implementations and the advantages and disadvantages associated with each.

```
1.Array-based implementation
2.Linked implementation
3.Blocked implementation
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been downvoted.  It's basic, but it seems fair.  Anyway, what do you mean by a blocked implementation?

Comment: I assume that a blocked implementation allocates a number of entries in an array (block) and link new blocks, if one block isn't enough to hold all entries.

Comment: This SO community is better suited for practical problems (I didn't down-vote, just observing). You might get a better response in one of the other SO community, maybe the [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) one... anyway, an Array implementation imposes a continuous memory limit, so you need to know the size of the stack before reserving it's memory (Windows use to do that) - this makes recursive algorithms tricky. Linked lists don't have that issue, but you do need to manage stack memory and memory fragmentation...

Comment: Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrolled_linked_list) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).

Comment: @Myst First, I applaud you for commenting rather than downvoting [without explanation]. As to array implementation, what about a dynamically growing/shrinking version that is a "smart" wrapper over `realloc`?

Comment: Sometimes I will use (1) and (2) together. An array of `struct` contains a `next` member, which instead of being a pointer for linked lists, is an index into the array. So I have an array of items which also link with indexes. So I do not need `malloc` for the next record, I just get the next array element. When stuff is done with, I reset the "stack pointer" to a remembered value. As for (3), it's *my* computer, so if the memory requirement is both large and uncertain, I will take as much memory as I can in the first place, rather than the timid and deferential "oh no, another app needs it".

Comment: @CraigEstey, thanks. As for growing/shrinking, I guess it really depends on the size of the data (and it's location). At some point the copying and moving of all that data just doesn't make sense from a performance perspective. We'll also be invalidating existing pointers (careful)... I would definitely avoid this for implementing the stack segment in a program, but I might use a dynamic array for a smaller localized stack.

Comment: @Myst I agree. My assumption here is that the stack is to "flatten" a recursive algorithm that would overflow any [sane] CPU stack. What I'd do [have done] is the list approach for the algorithm's stack itself. The free pool for the list elements uses [yet] another list. When the free pool is empty, I do a large alloc and split it to replenish the free list. That way, it's not fragmenting [as much] as when having a single malloc for each list element

Comment: @CraigEstey , you gave me something to think about. I'm thankful. I would probably have used a dynamic array of fixed sized array blocks rather the a linked list or a node for every object... But I don't think I ever had to implement data structures that expected so much data. I never had a hash table grow more the 16Gb or suffer so many collisions that made my shy away from using recursion.

Comment: @CraigEstey   I suddenly realized my comment was vague. I meant to write that I would probably have made a mess of things and that a linked list is probably the best approach, considering the number of possible nodes when flattening a large recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user of a stack implementation expects a dynamic data structure. C does not provide that directly in language terms. You have to allocate and administrate the memory your own.

Allocating an **array**, therefore a static sized structure, is very easy. However, you have the problem, that the number of maximum entries is limited. If you make the array too small, this will cause errors, if you make the array very big, you are waisting memory.

A solution for this is to dynamically reallocate the array, if the number of entries exceeds the array size. But this moves the whole memory to another place in memory, what has some disadvantages. (I. e. you have to copy the whole memroy and it is not possible to hold a pointer to a specific entry.)

Having a **linked list** is the contrary. You (dynamically) allocate memory for each entry. You can free the memory for a single entry on removing from stack. This sounds better, but has the caveat, that you spent a pointer size of memory for each entry. Typically this is the size for an entry. So you double the memory consumption. Beside this, allocating small pieces of memory over and over wastes memory, too.

So you can implement a **compromise**: A linked list of arrays: You allocate a block for a number of entries, let's say 256. Then you fill that block with entries, without reallocating or allocating memory. If the number of entries exceeds that value, you allocate a new block for additional 256 entries. The blocks are linked. So it is a linked list of arrays.

Esp. for a stack – you do not have removals in the middle of the structure – this is the best implementation in most cases.

Comment: Amin, nice answer. However, you're assuming that all the stack elements are the same size. This is a common use case, but not necessarily true. Variable size data is commonly saved outside the stack (the stack containing pointers to that data), this allows certainty at the cost of dereferencing data and possible paging. However, the data might also be saved inside the stack (think of the stack vs. heap in your program's memory)... These should also be considered when choosing the implementation type.

Comment: I did not assume that, but wrote: *This sounds better, but has the caveat, that you spent a pointer size of memory for each entry. Typically this is the size for an entry.* The reason for this was exactly, that the real data is outside the structure itself and referenced by a pointer. I did not write more about that, because this was not the core of his question. BTW: Having a generic stack structure you always use pointers. C does not have templates.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how much space each data structure takes, and whether you can do the stack operations on them efficiently; i.e., in O(1) time.

For a basic stack, you need to be able to push new elements onto the stack, and pop the most recently pushed (top) element off.  You probably also want to peek at the top element, and check if the stack is empty.

A dynamically sized array (or block, if I understand the OP's comment correctly) is fine for a stack.  It may be advantageous in certain situations if you will be accessing and changing the stack a lot, and want to avoid the small amount of extra work of allocating and destroying memory with each push or pop.  It also gives you direct, indexed access to everything in the stack, for extended functionality. The disadvantage is that the stack will use some extra space.

You can use a singly-linked-list list for a stack as well, pushing and popping at the head.  This is probably the most common type structure used if you don't need extended functionality like direct access to the elements besides the head, and if you aren't trying to implement something on the bleeding edge of time efficiency.